# The spring CRON expression for scheduling a CRON job to run at 6 AM from Tuesday to Saturday?

Tags: spring, cron

Is the below expression  the correct spring CRON expression for scheduling a CRON jon to run at 6 AM from Tuesday to Saturday?

`0 0 6 * * TUE-SAT`

This is the spring annotation I am using
`@Scheduled(cron="0 0 6 * * TUE-SAT")`

This expression is not firing up the job for me. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Below the code.

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class ExpireAccountsJob {


    // Runs at 6:00 AM daily On Tue/Wed/Thursday/Friday/Sat in Prod
    @Scheduled(cron = "${app.scheduler.expireAccountsJobSchedule}")
    public void run() throws UnknowHostException {

        String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();

        log.debug("ExpireAccounts:: host name:" + hostName);



        log.debug("Start ExpireAccounts on scheduler node");

        //Some business logic

        log.debug("End ExpireAccountson scheduler node");

    }
}
```

And below is the application.yml from where I am reading this property

```
app:
  scheduler:
    expireAccountsJobSchedule: 0 0 6 * * TUE-SAT
```

Comment: Could you add your configuration ? Config class for instance. Cron looks correct

Comment: Below is the code

Comment: If its a spring boot application, we need to use @EnableScheduling. Also refer - https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Answer (score 0):

`@Scheduled(cron="0 0 6 ? * TUE-SAT")` is more accurate.

However, I think it is not a stopper for the job to be fired but it will work every day not for the specific days you want because you put * (all days) in the day of month place.

However, I think the problem for you is the configuration which allows the applications to schedule jobs.

I think the annotation @EnableScheduling needs to be annotated at the top of the configuration class of your spring project and it must be added with the annotation @Configuration.

Otherwise, if you use XML for the configuration you should add that tag in your XML

```
task:annotation-driven
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed. I'll try this out. But can you tell me the difference between  @Scheduled(cron="0 0 6 ? * TUE-SAT")  and  @Scheduled(cron="0 0 6 * * TUE-SAT")